# Was the creature guarding the camp in the Dungeons and Dragons movie a beholder?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

In the 2000 movie *Dungeons and Dragons* we see a creature that looks like a floating meatball with eye stalks.  While at first glance, it looks like a [beholder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beholder_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)).  But did the script say that's what it really was? Or was it actually a [spectator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectator_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons))

Here is an example of the scene in question:

[image: early 2000s beholder CGI]

Comment: ... That's an actual shot of the movie and not a horribly bad photoshop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're **[beholders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beholder_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons))**. Snails identifies them thusly in a voiceover a few seconds before the scene pictured (when they climb up the grapple lines)

> **Snails:** *Ridley, look--**Beholders**.*
>
> **Ridley:** *Relax, Snails. We'll just sneak around 'em.*

You might wish to note that given the crudity of the CGI (and the fact that they don't interact with any of the actors) that they were probably dropped into the film long after the scene had been filmed and tested on audiences, explaining their total absence from the film's official novelisation.